# Cracking sound in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound

**Hello** I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I was just browsing the root folder and didn't change any thing then suddenly my laptop hung all the things were working in the background but mouse click was not working and it recovered automatically but my earphone was giving cracking sound very fast. I noticed that in settings ,sound output was changing from laptop speaker and earphones rapidly. So I restarted in Ubuntu and then booted in Windows and there also the problem exist. I know that the problem is Ubuntu. Also now laptops speaker's volume is changing rapidly. What should I do now?

Update :- 1) I tried restarting pulseaudio but no success.
2) I tied booting in recovery mode and then booting in regular mode and now its stable but don't know if it happens in future ?

Comment: Problem  in both Windows and Ubuntu not software it is a hardware problem. I would take the machine in for repair.

Comment: No is was fine I used my laptop yesterday for 8 hours! and its always fine. I think the problem was Ubuntu because I booted in recovery mode and then booted back in regular mode and now the problem is solved. But don't know will it occur again. @David